# Audiooutput problem in Qt using qmultimedia low level API

Tags: c++, qt, audio, qt4, multimedia

I'm trying to get mpg123 audio decoder to work with QT on windows. How do i play the decoded audio data at the right speed with Qmultimedia module in push mode. Currently i'm using simple timer to get it to play audio but it's not very efficient way to do it, if I do anything else at the same time audio get all distorted. Is there any better way to send the decoded data to audio output? It would be nice if anyone could point me to any nice examples using Qmultimedia module and Qaudiooutput class. I've tried to figure out QT example project "audiooutput" but it seems that it's also using timer to send audio to output in push mode.. Hope that I'm not too confusing.

Comment: Have you looked into using the higher level Qt library called Phonon? The use case is simple and standard.

Comment: There is also new qt-multimedia (currently only in qt-mobility) that is IMHO much better.

Answer (score 0):

I also had to figure that out and I would also suggest using the Phonon framework to do this.
It uses Windows Media Player as host on Windows, QuickTime on Mac and some KDE stuff on Linux.
So it's pretty platform independent.

If you need more low-level functionality, you should take a look into an open-source project called portaudio. It's very easy to use and you can manipulate or even fill buffers from code.
I used it to build an oscillator.

Hope that helps!

Best,

guitarflow